# How to filter Sidebar Content

Tags: filters, sidebar

I want to filter sidebar content generated from `dynamic_sidebar()` and only return the last 2 calendar years of archives (not last 24 months).

Is it possible to do this sort of filtering and how?

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to filter *whole sidebar* and such, but then that's not what you really need.

The calendar widget (assuming you mean native one) uses `get_calendar()` function, which passes result through `get_calendar` filter.

It would be preferable to filter its queries, but from quick look at the code they seem highly messy and not easy to override.